# Where does "X marauds as Y" in the sense of "X deceptively pretends to be Y" come from?

Tags: meaning

I was writing a sentence and tried to use the format "X marauds as Y".
As a (terrible) example:

> If violence cannot be contained, tamed, cornered, or corralled by narrative, it marauds as outlaw, outside of law, out of control, dangerous and unknowable.
> — [Some book on Google books](https://www.google.com.au/books/edition/Speaking_of_Violence/VDrn8JhPTmMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22marauds+as%22&pg=PA26&printsec=frontcover)

I've no idea where I picked it up from, but if you google the phrases "marauds as" you get various search results, but nothing really notable.

None of the dictionaries I can find have any definition for marauds but:

> to roam about and raid in search of plunder
> — Merriam Webster

Anyway, is there a proper definition for this? Or where does it come from?

Comment: The definition "to roam in search of things to steal or people to attack" is what *maraud* means, and [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/maraud) gives its origin. The quote you give seems to match this closely, while personifying violence as something roaming looking for things to attack. *As* can [refer](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/as) to function or character. I'm not sure what you want to know beyond what you get in dictionaries that you already seem to have consulted. What do you think maraud means, or what do you want it to mean?

Comment: Maybe it resembles *masquerades* a little, but it's not that.

Comment: As a prepositional phrase indicating an assumed character, *as* plus its object can indeed adverbially modify a great variety of verbs: "As Mercutio, Smith capered, mugged, whispered, and roared without restraint."

Comment: To be clear, the construction in *Speaking of Violence* is valid but unusual. The whole sentence is a bit poetic, with its descriptive series, and is consciously leveraging "marauds" into a syntax it would not normally lend itself to. I would not choose to replicate it in my writing, not because it was a bad idea, but because it fit in this context and might not in mine, and also because it was a very unique and "gestural" choice, and reusing it myself would border on plagiarism, at least of tone.

Comment: Perhaps I can illustrate with what I originally wanted to say: "The robot project marauds as a simple compiler project"; another google example is "Data sometimes marauds as something other than itself."

Comment: Maybe *masquerades* would work for you.